# Why does my iPhone iPod player lose its place when I sync?

Tags: itunes, iphone, sync

Whenever I sync my iPhone, my place in the various PodCasts I listen to is lost (well, synched to the position in iTunes which, because I don't use iTunes to listen to PodCasts, is zero).

Is there some obvious setting somewhere that I have missed that will use the iPhone position over the iTunes position?

**Update**

Looks like this is fixed with iOS 4.0.

Comment: s/loose/lose/ s/it's/its/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been running into this issue myself since upgrading to 3.0, and it feels like a bug. I'm not sure if the problem is with iTunes or the iPhone, and I don't know of a workaround.

The best thing you can do is [send feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) to Apple, or (if you're feeling ambitious) reduce the problem to a reproducible test case and [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Seems like it.  I'll leave the question open for a while, just in case there is an apple wonk out there who has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Genius" on your iPhone if you have it enabled.  (To do this, you need to disable it in iTunes and then sync your phone.)  This seems to have fixed it for me.

This issue has been driving me crazy for months, to the point that I would delay syncing my iPhone for days so that I wouldn't lose my place.  It seemed like it had something to do with the "mini-sync" that would happen immediately after I plugged in my phone (even though I have iTunes set to sync manually).  If I was in the iPod app on the phone when the mini-sync happened, it would say something like "Updating library" on the screen.

I didn't know what was causing the mini-sync, so I disabled other apps that I was using that read the iTunes library (last.fm scrobbler and Lala Mover), but it still happened.  The only thing left was Genius, and disabling that seems to have stopped the mini-sync and preserved my podcast markers.

Comment: Hrm. Tried that. Didnt work for me. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that this is related to the version of iTunes or the iPhone OS version you are running.

I have an iPhone 3G which I sync everyday with podcasts using iTunes 8.2.1 and it has yet to lose my position in a podcast.

The only setting I know off on the iPhone (OS3) is for remembering the position of movies.

- Settings
- iPod
- Video
- Start Playing

I know OS3 brought a lot of enhancements to the iPod application so it may be one of the new features.

Comment: I have a 3GS, I wonder if this is an introduced problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the options of your podcast files (Ctrl-click-Get Info; Options tab), and make sure "Remember playback position" is checked.

Comment: "Remember Playback Position" is checked on all the files I checked (including one that gets reset when I sync).  I guess I am looking for something a little more global.

Answer (score 0):

I also notice that since I upgraded to 3.0, it still remembers the location, but now always goes back to the podcast list.  So when I take the phone out of sleep, I now need an extra press (and sometimes, scroll) to get back to where I was.

Comment: If you don't have an actual answer, it's preferred that you write a comment instead.

Comment: You are correct, but at the time, I didn't have enough credits to write a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue. It seems to be been introduced since I have upgraded my phone to 3GS. Maybe it is a combination of iPhone 3GS and Firmware 3.0.

I don't have this problem with my 1st Generation iPhone with Firmware 3.0.

***This Issue has been resolved in iPhone 3.1 and iTunes 9.***